# PHP execute does not return any errors but no rows added in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP script that should be executed when the register button is clicked and if the address checkbox is checked.

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
   if($_POST['addressCheckBox']  == 'Yes'){
      if(isset($_POST['streetNumber']) && isset($_POST['route']) && isset($_POST['sublocality_level_1'])){
         $unitDetails = trim($_POST['unitDetails']);
         $streetNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['streetNumber']));
         $route = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['route']));
         $suburb = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['sublocality_level_1']));
         $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['city']));
         $zipCode = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['zipCode']));
         $province = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['province']));
         $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['country']));
         $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['email']));

         if(!empty($streetNumber)  && !empty($route) && !empty($city) && !empty($province) && !empty($zipCode) && !empty($country)){
            $queryInsertMemberAddress = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO address (memberEmail, unitDetails, houseNumber, streetName, suburb, city, postalCode, province, country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            $queryInsertMemberAddress->bind_param('ssisssiss', $email, $unitDetails, $streetNumber, $route, $suburb, $city, $zipCode, $province, $country);

            $queryInsertMemberAddress->execute() or die($queryInsertMemberAddress->error);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When the script runs I don't get any errors but **no rows are INSERTED in the database.** I tried to find errors by doing the following:

1. execute a **var_dump** on the $queryInsertMemberAddress after **->execute()** and it returns

   ```
   object(mysqli_stmt)[19]
      public 'affected_rows' => null
      public 'insert_id' => null
      public 'num_rows' => null
      public 'param_count' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'errno' => null
      public 'error' => null
      public 'error_list' => null
      public 'sqlstate' => null
      public 'id' => null
   ```
2. execute a **print_r** on the $queryInsertMemberAddress variable after **->execute()** and it returns

   ```
   mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 1 [insert_id] => 28 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 9 [field_count] => 0 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 4
   ```

I can't understand why the print_r shows that one row was affected but no records show in the database. Does anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: Does PHP enter the conditional?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes it does. I've tested it by using echo to make sure that It actually enters all four conditional statements

Comment: @Hozington And the db connection?

Comment: you don't need all those `mysqli_real_escape_string`s with parameterized queries

Comment: @NirjharLo the db connection works. I have another script that isn't related to this one in the same file that runs perfectly.

Comment: _“[insert_id] => 28”_ – is there a record with that id in the database? If not - are you looking into the _correct_ database?

Comment: @Martin I thought so as well but I'm new to parameterized queries so I wasn't really sure if I had to use them or not. I'll remove them afterwards.

Comment: @Martin  I forgot to add the $email variable when I was typing on stackoverflow. I've just added it. But it is present in my current script

Comment: @CBroe There are records with insert_id => 28. For now I only have 20, 22, 25 which I added manually as part of my testing.

Answer (score 0):

## Broad Concerns

Every time you call a method of the database class, you should wrap it in an `if` statement to check if it executed correctly, and to then feedback any errors found.

- [MySQL error reporting setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/3536236)

  ```
   if(!$queryInsertMemberAddress = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO address (memberEmail, ... , country) VALUES (?,...,?)")){
       die("failed prepare: ".$db->error);
   }
   if(!$queryInsertMemberAddress->bind_param('ssisssiss', $email, ..., $country)){
       die("failed binding: ".$queryInsertMemberAddress->error);
   }
   if(!$queryInsertMemberAddress->execute()){
         die("failed execution: ".$queryInsertMemberAddress->error);
   }
  ```
- Remove all your `mysqli_real_escape_string` calls, they're redundant.
- Is your MySQL user allowed to insert data into that table? Does your user specified in your PHP connection have permission to `INSERT`?

---

I may be completely wrong here, but I *think* what may be going on is your `bind_param` statement is sabotaging your SQL.

Bind Param requires the given elements to be of the type specified in the first string, you have `ssisssiss` which is all **strings** with a few **integers** mixed in. That's fine, but your *data* is all derived from `$_POST` elements ***which are always strings***.

So if you var_dump the data you are inserting then you will var_dump a lot of `(string)` type values. And no `(int)` type values.

Example

```
 $_POST['value'] = "1"; //this is a string
 $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,trim($_POST['value'])); //optional, from your code...
 var_dump($value); /// (string)"1";
```

But you can't turn Bind Param into all strings (`sssssssss`) because this will then mismatch with the data types of the MySQL columns you're trying to insert into.

What I believe is happening is that due to these type mismatches the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is missing values and/or aborting the whole SQL and for some reason not giving you apporpriate error feedback.

**How to check**

```
if(!$queryInsertMemberAddress->bind_param('ssisssiss', $email, $unitDetails, ...) ){
    die("bind failed"); //bind_param returns true or false 
}
```

## Solution Suggestion:

```
$streetNumber = (int)$streetNumber;
$zipCode = (int)$zipCode;
```

Please let me know how this goes and what results this presents to you.